# AWS CodePipeline Not Respecting CodeBuild Settings

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am currently creating a pipeline using codepipeline, codebuild, codedeploy and codecommit. I encountered a problem when my uploading codebuild build artifacts to s3 because it does not follow the artifact name i setup in my buildspec.yml:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/build/*'
  name: build-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Instead it randomly creates a build name. In my codebuild settings i already enabled semantic versioning but it seems like its being ignored by codepipeline because i can see in the logs that there is a difference when generating the build artifacts if i run codepipeline or i run codebuild only.

This is what's being displayed in the logs for codebuild only:

```
[Container] 2019/08/08 09:28:07 Assembling file list 
[Container] 2019/08/08 09:28:07 Expanding **/build/* 
[Container] 2019/08/08 09:28:08 Found 144 file(s) 
[Container] 2019/08/08 09:28:08 Updating artifact name as  build-2019-08-08
```

This is what's being displayed in the logs for codepipeline:

```
[Container] 2019/08/08 09:19:50 Assembling file list 
[Container] 2019/08/08 09:19:50 Expanding **/build/* 
[Container] 2019/08/08 09:19:50 Found 144 file(s) 
[Container] 2019/08/08 09:19:50 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
```

You can see that the **Updating artifact name as  build-2019-08-08** line is not present in the logs when i run codepipeline.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use CodeBuild as a build or test step in your CodePipeline, your pipeline controls the artifact naming. Meaning, artifact naming is managed by CodePipeline and can't be overriden.

You have a 3-stage pipeline, CodeCommit -> CodeBuild -> CodeDeploy. When configuring the pipeline, you configure the output artifact name which acts as the input for the next stage. Having these artifacts names be pipeline-defined enables changes to flow through in a versioned manner.